# Can I pause my Wudu' a little?

Tags: fiqh, fatwa, wudu

Nowadays, it is really cold in our country.

When I am making *Wudu'* I was wondering if it is allowed to pause after washing my hands to the elbow to drain them, and get my blouse down, then continue my hair and my feet?

Note that I am still continuing my Wudu', still near the tap, just draining my hands, and the intent (Niah) in Wudu' is found.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, you're not asking about the water itself being too cold, you're just asking about it being too cold to leave your arms wet and bare for long after washing them?

Comment: Yes the purpose iI'm asking is: being too cold to leave my arms wet and bare for long after washing them.

Comment: Some Shia scholars say: there can be small gaps between Wudu' such that your hands and face are not dry before finishing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to exactly found the Hadith pertaining to allowing any time gap between steps in the *wudu'*, but heard in many *bayaans*, and read it several times in books that *wudu'* should be performed at once i.e. without any time gap between the steps.

[This link](http://www.islamic-laws.com/WudhuTayammumGhusl.htm) has the following

> Q) What are the conditions for the validity of Wudhu?
>   ...
>   (10)  ﻿The acts of Wudhu should be done one after the other, without ﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿time gap in between.

The above link has a lot more information.

Besides, if possible try to use warm water. Just boil it for few minutes and that would be good. In many places I have witnessed this.

Answer (score 1):

there is instruction in wudu that name is **muwalat** it means that we don't pause many times from the levels of wudu.

if we pause a little, and people realize that we are washing for prayers its possible and people don't realize that the wudu is wrong.