# Is pausing my wudu allowed if I have to leave the room and come back while in the middle of wudu?

Tags: fiqh, shiism, wudu

I was making wudu and all I had left were my arms and feet, but my dad was upset with me and he told me to come down immediately even though I was almost done. When I finished talking to him, I went back to make wudu. All parts that were previously washed during wudu, were dry except for my head. I only finished my feet and I prayed. Is this permissible from a Shia point of view?

Comment: Have your other body parts become dry -naturally- when you continued?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pause my Wudu' a little?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/can-i-pause-my-wudu-a-little)

Comment: Yes they all did except for my head. And I am asking in a Shia perspective

Answer (score 2):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

It ought to be noted that Urfi Mowaalaat --being successive-- in doing Wudhu practices is a condition; namely: it is necessary not to make a much Faasilah (interval) between Wudhu's practices; but walking (only) some foots between Mash (wetting/anointing ...) of head and foot.

Of note, if this interval is led in drying the moisture of hand palms, (thus), it must be used of face hairs or hand, in order to wet the palm of hand, and the Wudhu is invalid if there is no wetness.

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa30713)